# Can't add image to the sellable item

Tags: sitecore-commerce, media-library

We are using Sitecore 9 Update 2 + Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 2.

Search field didn't return any result when I'm trying to add an image to the sellable item. As a key, I use image name. 
Before that, I republished all site and rebuilt all indexes.
[image]
[image]

I heard it's known issue for Commerce team, but didn't found any information about it.

Comment: Did you rebuild indexes? When you search it use sitecore indexes

Comment: @VladIobagiu, yes I did it.

Comment: Can you try to search * 153 * .  Delete the space between digits and *

Comment: @VladIobagiu, the same result. But when I search image by name from the content editor it working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search in Commerce is using [OData Item Service](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_odata_item_service). 
Except for term, you type in Search dialog, additional filters might be used. Filters are defined by the OData Item API Key. 
In a default configuration commerce habitat and adventure environments are using

> 34905B27-5F55-4DF8-B866-B60A1571D2D5

as API key. This item is located in core database and contains filter below:

> (Fields/any(f: (f/Name eq 'Extension' and (f/Value eq 'png' or f/Value
>   eq 'jpg'))) and Language eq 'en' and (contains(Path,
>   '/images/adventure') or contains(Path, '/images/habitat'))))

As you can see, the search is done only for images with extensions *.png and *.jpg and only under the habitat and adventure folders.

You should either register your own filter and update environment configuration or, as a fast change, update existing one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but now from XC 9.1, `{34905B27-5F55-4DF8-B866-B60A1571D2D5}` item is in **Master** database instead **Core** database, and other things are the same as stated above.
Location is - `/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys/CommerceMediaItemsODataAPIKey`